# Overload how an object instance of a class is treated when used

Tags: opengl, c++, glsl, c

So I've made this struct that encapsulates a `glm::vec4`. This is because `vec3`s are treated as 16-byte in GLSL, but I don't want to assign a `vec4` if I only really need 3 components. Anyway, my question isn't really OpenGL/GLSL specific, but since it is in this context it would be easier to post it here.

Below is my "overloaded vec3", and some code for how I use it:

```
struct GpuVec3
{
public:
    GpuVec3() {}

    GpuVec3& GpuVec3::operator=(const vec3& other) 
    {
        v.x = other.x;
        v.y = other.y;
        v.z = other.z;
        v.w = 1.0f;

        return *this;
    }

private:
    vec4 v;
};

// ...

// Struct using GpuVec3 members
struct Material
{
public:
    GpuVec3 Emissive;
    GpuVec3 Ambient; 
    GpuVec3 Diffuse;
    GpuVec4 SpecularAndShininess;
};

// Assign vec3 to GpuVec3 (works fine)
material->Emissive = vec3(0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

// ... initializing uniform block and stuff ...

// Passing Emissive to function that expects vec3 (doesn't work, of course)
// UniformBlock3fv(GLchar* uniformBlockName, GLchar* uniformName, glm::vec3 value)
program->UniformBlock3fv("uniMaterial", "Emissive", material->Emissive);
```

In the last line of code I want to be able to pass my `GpuVec3` to a function that expects a `vec3`, this is not possible of course.

My question is, is there some way in C/C++ possible to overload how an object instance of a class is treated when used? A pseudo-code example below what I want to happen if I use my object:

```
if (material->Emissive is called) { return v.xyz; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would do to keep your GPUVec3 and your vec3 as two separate classes, not one containing the other. Here's an example:

```
struct vec3
{
    float x,y,z;
};

struct GPUVec3
{
    float x,y,z, pad;

    GPUVec3() { }
    GPUVec3( float x, float y, float z ) { }
    GPUVec3( const vec3 & v ) { }

    operator vec3 const & () const { return *(vec3*)this; }

} __attribute__ ((aligned(16)));
```

I have also provided an overload that lets you assign from vec3 to GPUVec3 and back again. This isn't a complete implementation, but you get the idea - using constructors and overloads it is possible to get the conversions to be called automatically. The takeaway here is that vec3 doesn't need to be 16 byte aligned, but *can* be. Since you can assign a GPUVec3 back to a reference to a vec3, you can read back and pass around a GPUVec3's xyz without copying. The same is not true for vec3 - it is not *always* 16 byte aligned (but could be) so you can't safely just cast it to a GPUVec3. This lets you put vec3s wherever you need and only have to worry about the 16-byte alignment interchange with the GPU in gpu-centric variables.

This stack exchange has a great overview of the C++ operator idioms and includes something on assignment idioms. MOre can be found, fore sure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Here's an example in use and compiles fine under xcode:

```
int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) 
{

    GPUVec3 gpuVec3;

    vec3 from;

    gpuVec3 = from;

    vec3 to = gpuVec3;


    // insert code here...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this did it! However, I'm wondering why you use both a `float pad` and `__attribute__ ((aligned(16)))`? Right now I'm running with just the float and it's working nice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an user-defined conversion, something like this:

```
struct GpuVec3
{
public:
    GpuVec3() {}

    GpuVec3& GpuVec3::operator=(const vec3& other) 
    {
        v.x = other.x;
        v.y = other.y;
        v.z = other.z;
        v.w = 1.0f;

        return *this;
    }

    operator glm::vec3() const { return v.xyz; }

private:
    vec4 v;
};
```

You can read more about it here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator